# How to combine 2 parameters in Prepared statement

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I want to convert below java **Statement** into **PreparedStatement** combining 2 parameters i.e. input1 and input2. How to do that?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input1="Hello";
        String input2="World";

        try {

            String sql = "select * from veracodetable where output = \'"  +input1 + input2+ "\'";
            statement = con.createStatement();
            statement.executeQuery(sql);
            rs = s.getResultSet();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
String sql = "select * from veracodetable where output = ?";
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(input1+input2);
statement.executeQuery();
rs = s.getResultSet();
```

Of course the `PreparedStatement` would have just one parameter, as you can see.

Comment: Thanks! I never thought of **statement.setString(input1+input2);**. I was trying to give 2 "?" in query itself